# Glassfish. The requested resource () is not available

Tags: java, maven, glassfish

I've got a glassfish v3 install.

I'm using Maven to deploy my application.

But when i try to launch application the browser comes back with:

*The requested resource () is not available.*

Any ideas?

Comment: The app isn't starting up? It's not deployed where you think it is?

Comment: Please add your server.log or other additional information so we don't have to rely on our crystal ball...

Comment: Are you sure you are hitting the right url? with the web context prefix?

Answer (score 0):

```
When you launch an application from the admin console, you will access
it at its document root. In your example, the launch link would look
as follows:

localhost:8080/HelloWorldServlet/

When you access an application at its document root, the container
will check the application's document root folder for any welcome pages.

You can define your own welcome page(s) in your application, but
unless you do so, your application will inherit a predefined list of welcome
pages from your domain's default-web.xml descriptor, which looks like this:


index.html
index.htm
index.jsp

    Try placing a file with one of the above names in your application's document root, and      you'll notice that when you click on the launch link for your
app, the contents of its welcome page will be served.

    If your app does not contain any welcome pages, the container would
    normally generate a directory listing of its docroot folder. By
    default, this functionality is disabled for security reasons, but can
    be enabled by setting the init parameter with name "listings" of the
    "default" Servlet, which is declared in default-web.xml, to "true".
    This will enable directory listings globally (for all apps).
    Alternatively, you
    may enable directory listings for your app only, by setting "listings" to
    "true" in your app's sun-web.xml descriptor.
```

Ref: https://www.java.net//node/700171